# Why can't I solve my PDE this way?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm preparing for my stochastic calculus final and I'm having some problem solving the PDEs that come out of it. The PDE I have is:

$u_t(t,x) + \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}(t,x)=0$

With the boundary condition:

$u(T,x)=e^{-\gamma x^2}$

My professor showed us a way, but its not one I'm hyper comfortable with. I tried to do it in a way that feels natural to me, but it doesn't seem to be working out.

Following the professor's at first, I start with the proposed solution:

$u(t,x)=e^{a(t)x^2+b(t)x+c(t)}$

So, with this:

$u_t=(a'x^2+b'x+c')u$

$u_x=(2ax+b)u$

$u_{xx}=((2ax+b)^2+2a)u = (4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2+2a)u$

To satisfying the PDE, we need $a'x^2+b'x+c'+\frac{1}{2}(4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2+2a)=0$. We can do this by setting the coefficients in front of $x^2$, $x$, and $1$ to zero. Here is where I diverge from my professor's approach. I tried:

$a'+2a^2=0 \Rightarrow \frac{da}{dt}=-2a^2 \Rightarrow a^{-2}da=-2dt \Rightarrow a^{-1} = 2t \Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{2t}$

$b'+2ab=0 \Rightarrow b'+\frac{b}{t}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{db}{dt}=\frac{-b}{t} \Rightarrow -\frac{db}{b}=\frac{dt}{t} \Rightarrow -ln(b)=ln(t) \Rightarrow b=\frac{1}{t}$

Of course, we can also have $b=0$. I supposed I could see this is the correct solution since I need $b(T)=0$. So let's go with that and move on to $c$

$c'+a=0  \Rightarrow c=-\frac{1}{2t} \Rightarrow c =\frac{1}{2}ln(t)$

This seems wrong for two reasons: (1) the solution doesn't leave any room to enforce my boundary conditon; and (b) the solution the professor showed is different.

Comment: Is $u_xx$ supposed to be $u_{xx}$?

Comment: @Dave yes, thank you! I fixed it.

Comment: Why did $4a^2$ become $2a^2$, and $4ab$ become $2ab$?

Comment: @angryavian because of the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the original PDE.

Comment: $$c  = \color{red}{-} \frac{1}{2} \ln t$$ Also, perhaps you might like to show us your lecturers solution so we can see _how_ the two solutions differ.

Comment: @roundsquare There is a $1/2$ missing in the sentence "To satisfying the PDE, we need ..."

Comment: You forgot the constant. $a^{-2}da=-2dt \Rightarrow a^{-1} = 2t + const$. Ditto for $b$.